# calendar, block year

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I'm creating a DatePicker in a dialog, following this tutorial:

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/using-android-date-picker/

Now, I want the only year available are 2012 and 2013.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: tell me which api level are you targetting? whats ur min api level?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't open for me.  But what's wrong with using `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate`?

Comment: Don't use Date picker dialog which is deprecated...use Date Dialog Fragment...You can use setMaxDate and setMinDate methods but...Don't use Date picker dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) in Android.

And use `DatePicker.setMaxDate()` and `DatePicker.setMinDate()` to set a fixed year.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following parameters if you define it in a `Layout`:

```
android:maxDate="12/31/2013"
android:minDate="01/01/2012"
```

or if you are not defining it in xml, use:

```
Calendar c_max = Calendar.getInstance(), c_min = Calendar.getInstance();
c_min.set(2012,0,1);
c_max.set(2013,11,31);
DatePicker.setMaxDate(c_max.getTimeInMillis());
DatePicker.setMinDate(c_min.getTimeInMillis());
```